# Dotnet-watch autoreloading the browser on a code change doesn't work anymore, even though the browser shows a change; works from VS Pro via Ctrl+F5

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-5

At some point, autoreloading (autorefreshing) the page with **`dotnet watch`** has stopped working, although it used to refresh itself just fine.

When I make a change to certain files, `dotnet watch` starts to rebuild my project.  In the browser, I get the glyph showing that there is a pending change: [image].  Then in the dotnet-watch terminal, I get `Now listening on: https://localhost:5001` and `Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.`, telling me the build is done and the web server restarted using the new binaries. But the browser doesn't actually refresh the page like it used to.  The behavior is the same whether I use Chrome, Firefox, or Edge.

Also, I have noticed that CSS hot reload works great too...a change to a CSS shows up in my browser without a page reload.  It is just that the browser isn't refreshing after the build from `dotnet watch` completes like it used to.

Finally, when I start from Visual Studio Professional using Ctrl+F5, the autoreload works again (via IIS Express instead of Kestrel).  **What could make this** last step work when started via VS but **fail silently when started via `dotnet watch`**?

This is a .NET 5 Blazor WebAssembly site, and I have installed MS Build 17.0.0-preview-21501-01+bbcce1dff as part of .NET 6 preview.

Any ideas what I can check?

Comment: Could this be related to the removal of hot reload from dotnet watch in .NET 6? https://www.theverge.com/2021/10/22/22740701/microsoft-dotnet-hot-reload-removal-decision-open-source - They've said it will be back in the release version but I haven't read enough to know if it was reinstated in a release candidate.

Comment: That was my thought too, but this broke months ago, well before any change, back when I had preview 2. I now have preview 7. This is not full hot reloading (the new feature in .NET 6), but just auto-rebuilding and auto-refreshing that used to work great in .NET 5.